# coloring first row in multi tables with jquery

Tags: jquery, row, html-table

i am using this css code:

```
.even{
    background: #E4ECF6;
}
.odd{
    background: #F3F7FB;
}
.firstrow{
    background-color: #599ECF;
}
```

i am using this css jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table tr:even').addClass('even');
$('table tr:odd').addClass('odd');
$('table tr:first').addClass('firstrow');
});
```

this code run correctly for first table. but when i have two or higher table ,this code can coloring first row of first table. is better code for coloring all first rows in all tables?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838880/how-to-select-first-row-of-the-first-table-in-an-html-page-using-jquery

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838880/how-to-select-first-row-of-the-first-table-in-an-html-page-using-jquery) ask first row of multi table alone, but i want first rows of all tables.

Comment: Turns out this is a duplicate of [Selecting first row from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1843440/1402846).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$('table tr:first').addClass('firstrow');
```

with

```
$('table tr:first-child').addClass('firstrow');
```

The key is to use the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector, which

> Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XK6CT/).

---

In case you still want to the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('table tr:even').addClass('even');
  $('table tr:odd').addClass('odd');
  $('table').each(function () {  // For each 'table'...
    $(this).find('tr:first').addClass('firstrow');  // Add class 'firstrow' to the first 'tr'.
  });
});
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XK6CT/2/).